# Online index operation blocking inserts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, nonclustered-index

I am trying to create a non clustered index on a table which is around 500GB.  The table already has a clustered index on it. Since we do not want other transaction to be blocked we tried using `ONLINE=ON`, however at the beginning of the index build it blocked other OLTP transactions.

When I checked what locks were being held I noticed exclusive table lock on the table and other transactions are getting blocked by this.

Screen shot:

[image]

I look at [Guidelines for Online Index Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/guidelines-for-online-index-operations) for exclusions and its not applicable for this table.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding an index `online` doesn't allow you to completely avoid locking - when the process completes the table is locked for a brief period and the new index replaces the old one.

Online index operations need to take two very short-term table locks. Shared)table lock at the start of the operation to force all write plans that could touch the index to recompile, and a SCH-M (Schema-Modification) table lock at the end of operation to force all read and write plans that could touch the index to recompile.

And the article you provided has some info on this as well:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I read that, but as we can see from the screenshot, its an exclusive lock and also the locking happened at the beginning of the index creation.

Comment: In an online rebuild, the X locks you are seeing are on the new index structure being built, not the current index structure

Comment: ok, but then it wouldn't explain the blocking which I am seeing at the starting the index creation.

Comment: there is also a lock at the beginning of rebuild. So if you hace any data modification activity it is likely to see blicking at this stage

Comment: @SmokingDBA - Note that, since this is the creation of a new index, there's no existing index; any chance that would result in different locking activity than rebuild. I know the rebuild is functionally creating a new index, but could this be part of the issue?

Comment: Note that the exclusive lock is taken to update statistics. It may be taken for a short time - but a short time on a 500GB table may not be as short as you'd like. May want to try updating stats in advance, or temporarily disabling stats updates on the table and its object (may or may not make a diff). Also, make sure that your edition of SQL Server allows online  index creation (not sure if it fails with an error in editions that don't allow it, or if it's ignored.

Comment: @RDFozz, Thanks, Edition is not the problem as we have done online index creation on other similarly used table.  So I guess the question is why it is doing an update stats.  I will try disabling auto update stats on the table and give it a try.